# Get context of a decorated function

Tags: javascript, decorator, typescript2.0

How to Get context of a decorated function?
I use TypeScript as a transpiler. The sample is complicated because in my case it is an inversifyjs container and a decorator applied to a method. Locator calls the method and applies the context and arguments. The new decorated function is called. I need to call the real method. The problem is that I can not find it. Target variable does not point to the actual context. And context in descriptor.value is shown as undefined. This variable is undefined. Is it impossible in JavaScript?